# Plot change in pixel value in video as a function of time in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm relatively new to Matlab and wanted to plot the change in a pixel's value in a video. Essentially, I would randomly assign a pixel in the video to be tracked and the script would plot the value for that pixel throughout the course of the video.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's open a MATLAB example file:

```
v = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4')
```

and track a pixel near the middle of the movie:

```
row = 120;
col = 160;
```

We iterate over all frames. For each frame we extract the `(r,g,b)` color value of the pixel with coordinates `(row,col)` in the frame, convert it to luminance, and collect it in vector `L`:

```
L = [];
while hasFrame(v)
    video = readFrame(v);
    r = video(row, col, 1);
    g = video(row, col, 2);
    b = video(row, col, 3);
    lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;
    L = [L lum];
end
```

Finally we plot the luminance over time:

```
plot(L)
ylim([0,255])
```

It looks like this:

[image]